# Bootstrap tooltips internalization - translate title attribute

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization, pyramid, chameleon

I use some bootstrap tooltips ( http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips ) in my .pt file in a pyramid / python project. How to translate title attribute text using i18n:translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved adding i18n:attributes="title"